# Compare a ListBox Item with ListView item based on indexes

Tags: c#, listview, listbox

I am new to c#. In my project I have two controls ListBox and ListView

```
ListBox --> lbxEmpName
ListView --> lvEmpDetails
```

I tried the below code:

```
     if (lvEmpDetails.Items.Count > 0)
       {
           for (int intCount = 0; intCount < lbxEmpName.Items.Count; intCount++)
           {
              for (int intSubCount = 0; intSubCount < lvEmpDetails.Items.Count; intSubCount++)
              {
                 if (lvEmpDetails.Items[intSubCount].Equals(lbxEmpName.Items[intCount]))
                 {
                    lbxEmpName.Items.Remove(lbxEmpName.Items[intCount]);
                 }
              }
           }
       }
```

If I run the above code, there are no matches between ListView Items and ListBox Items (Infact there must be some matches). When I debug my code, I saw the below thing: It is saying `SelectedItem` whereas I am giving here `Items` (Thats why my program is not matching items)

 why it is showing `SelectedItem = ""` instead of `Items` ?
 Am I doing something wrong in my code? Please suggest.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to click that '+' icon to get the items.

Comment: There are items in listBox.. what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: As your screenshot shows there are 10 items in listbox. try browsing "Non-public Members" by clicking + there. you will get items inside that

Comment: @Maheep I know there are items in ListBox, my question is why those are not being compared with Listview control items. Did i write my code wrong? I was confused by seeing the `SelectedItem = ""`. Thank you for making me understand the concept of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView's `Items` contains objects of type `ListViewItem`. So there is no use in comparing those with objects in ListBox's `Items`.
If you want to compare their text, you must write something like this:

```
if (lvEmpDetails.Items[intSubCount].Text == (string)lbxEmpName.Items[intCount])
{
     // Do something here
}
```

Please note that a `ListViewItem` can have multiple sub-items and its `Text` property returns the first column of its data.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the string values that you want to compare not the object themselves.